# curved perspective

Tags: inkscape, perspective

In Inkscape, I am trying to recreate the illusion of corrugated metal on an airplane wing (such as on a Douglas TBD Devastator, if that information helps). The wing is curved, of course.

I am trying to get parallel boxes with rounded ends (representing the raised metal) to fit into a trapezoid with curved ends. I tried Extensions→modify path→perspective, but it doesn't seem to work if the box has curved ends (according to [Quick Inkscape Tutorial – Perspective Transforms](http://www.built-to-spec.com/blog/2011/01/02/quick-inkscape-tutorial-perspective-transforms/#:%7E:text=Basically%2C%20the%20old%20path%20for,Basically%20as%20of%20Inkscape%200.48.)).

What should I do?

Comment: It's not an accurate scale model I'm working on, so the exact number of corrugation ridges doesn't matter; the idea was to suggest a distinctive feature of the aircraft, since leaving the surface smooth would not capture the aircraft design of the period as well. I'd love to upload my file, but I can't see how to do that D:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's quite an old tutorial you've linked to. Inkscape 1.0 now has additional options, specifically Live Path Effects that can be used to do various distortions.

For example, the Perspective LPE available in the Path Effects

[image]

Also you can have more than one LPE effect. Here is the same graphic but with an additional Envelope Deformation LPE to curve the already perspective distorted image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just downloaded the newest version! :D